# Need help getting string values after Regex matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have trouble trying to get values into the database in order. Should I put the matches values into a list then to the database?

RegexWriter is a function to write to a textfile

String dash is to update a dash to a database if any of the fields are empty

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamWriter (DestinationTextBox.Text + "\\" + fileName))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var lines = reader.ReadLine ();
        var values = line.split (',');

        foreach (string value in values)
        {
            Match MatchName = Regex.Match (value.ToString (), RegexName);
            Match MatchClass = Regex.Match (value.ToString (), RegexClass);
            Match MatchTime = Regex.Match (value.ToString (), RegexTime)

            if (MatchesName.Success) {
                RegexWriter (MatchesName.value, fileName);
            } else {
                string dash = "-";
                RegexWriter (dash, fileName);
            }

            if (MatchesClass.Success) {
                RegexWriter (MatchesClass.value, fileName);
            } else {
                string dash = "-";
                RegexWriter (dash, fileName);
            }

            if (MatchesTime.Success) {
                RegexWriter (MatchesTime.value, fileName);
            } else {
                string dash = "-";
                RegexWriter (dash, fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the RegexWriter function

```
private void RegexWriter (string Input, fileName)
{
    string matchValue = Input;

    streamwriter = fileStreamWriter;
    fileStreamWriter = new StreamWriter (@"users\Admin\Desktop\DailyAttendance" + "\\" + fileName)
    fileStreamWriter.WriteLine(Input);
    fileStreamWriter.Flush();
    fileStreamWriter.Close();    

}
```

Comment: What database are you using, and do you have access to modify tables on it?

Comment: I’m using MySQL, yes I have access to modify the tables!  Updating to the tables seem fine but I there’s a problem with the if statement not being able to fill the correct data   To the correct names

Comment: Include the `RegexWriter` code please.And could you not just allow `Nulls` in the columns to avoid inserting a dash?

Comment: Sorry For the late reply, was in class. To provide some context, RegexWriter writes it to a TextFile first. The updating of the database is done separately . Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what each `line` contains or what `RegexName`, `RegexClass`, or `RegexType` are, my guess is that you are overwriting the value of the field because the last statement that runs for each `value` is:

```cs
if (MatchesTime.Success) {
    RegexWriter (MatchesTime.value, fileName);
} else {
    string dash = "-";
    RegexWriter (dash, fileName);
}
```

Assuming that the regular expressions are meant to be mutually exclusive, then what I think you actually want is:

```cs
if (MatchesName.Success) {
    RegexWriter (MatchesName.value, fileName);
} else if (MatchesClass.Success) {
    RegexWriter (MatchesClass.value, fileName);
} else if (MatchesTime.Success) {
    RegexWriter (MatchesTime.value, fileName);
} else {
    string dash = "-";
    RegexWriter (dash, fileName);
}
```